# Curl response from rest api - remove headers [PHP]

Tags: php, curl

I am using PHP Curl lib to make some REST API request. My code looks like:

```
// set up the curl resource
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host."/oauth/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',                                                                                
    'Authorization: Basic '.$token.''          
));       

// execute the request

$output = curl_exec($ch);

// output the authorization information - includes the header

 echo($output) . PHP_EOL;
```

And response looks like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate Pragma: no-cache Expires: 0 X-Frame-Options: DENY Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true Cache-Control: no-store Pragma: no-cache Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8 Content-Length: 498 Date: Tue, 11 Aug 2015 10:38:25 GMT {"access_token":"access_token_here","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":43199,"scope":"read write","jti":"jti_code_here"}
```

only thing I need from here is `access_token`, how ever I try to edit my $`output` only way I know to get to access token is to substr some chars, is there a way how remove headers and use rest of the response as array or json or something which i can access easy?

Thanks for any advise.

Comment: Use a JSON Parser to parse your output.

Comment: Hi @TarunUpadhyay yea I can think abou t it but how would I remove that headers from answer? :)

Comment: Make this change in your request. curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); Then you should not get the header.

Comment: this will remove HEADERS from reuqst not from response, isn't it? In request i need headers:)

Comment: In [PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php): `CURLOPT_HEADER - TRUE to include the header in the **output**. `

Comment: Oh sorry, I expect something what wasn't true . Thanks guys:)